# Weighted edges in R/igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using R & the `igraph` package to plot a graph written in graphml and I want to use the `weight` parameter included in this syntax

```
<edge id="e389" source="w4" target="w0">
    <data key="d1">0.166666666667</data>
</edge>
```

I can get the values with

```
weight = E(f)$weight  // f is the graph
```

but I don't know how to use `weight` before calculating the `df = degree(f)`

For further information: all nodes are connected to each other and the weight is 1 / (number_of_nodes - 1) so the degree for each node should be 1.

graphml file

```
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
<key id="d0" for="node" attr.name="label" attr.type="string"/>
<key id="d1" for="edge" attr.name="weight" attr.type="float"/>
<key id="d2" for="node" attr.name="type" attr.type="string"/>
<key id="d3" for="node" attr.name="tweet" attr.type="int"/>
<key id="d4" for="node" attr.name="color" attr.type="string"/>
<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
<node id="w4">
    <data key="d0">value1</data>
    <data key="d2">word</data>
    <data key="d1">0.166666666667</data>
    <data key="d4">green</data>
</node>
.
.
.
<node id="w2">
    <data key="d0">value2</data>
    <data key="d2">word</data>
    <data key="d1">0.166666666667</data>
    <data key="d4">green</data>
</node>
<edge id="e389" source="w4" target="w0">
    <data key="d1">0.166666666667</data>
</edge>
```

Comment: Any chance of a sample graphml file? I'm confused because I don't see a `weight` parameter in your XML - I see a `d1` property of an *edge*, and your R code is getting properties of a *vertex*...

Comment: @spacedman post updated and yes, you were right on the error in R code getting properties of vertex. Corrected as well

Comment: What do you mean "calculating the df=degree(f)"? You say each vertex is connected to every other vertex, so `degree(f)` is just number-of-vertexes minus one for each vertex. Do you really want the sum of edge weights for each vertex? That's not the degree...

Comment: @spacedman I explained it very bad so :) I need my degree (just discovered it's called weighted degree in this case) to be 1 in each of these nodes and I want to obtain this using the edges weight equal to 1 / (number_of_nodes - 1) for each edge. Only I don't know the syntax and the commands because I'm using R since a few days

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you are not looking for the `degree()` because this does not care about the edge weights. Are you probably looking for the `graph.strength()` function?

```
# create fully connected graph
g <- graph.full(10)

# assign weights such that every weight is 1/number_of_nodes -1
E(g)$weight <- 1/( length( V(g) ) -1 )

# calculate the "weighted degree"
graph.strength(g)

[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Alternatively, are you maybe looking for the normalized degree?

```
degree( g, normalized = TRUE )

[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Perfect! graph.strength() is exactly what I need. Thank you very much